# Non thread-safe code unexpectedly giving repeatable results

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

This is a question on a test. I have run the code many times and get the same answer: 999999. They say that this code will not produce the same results every time even though synchronized is present when writing the runLoop method. What am I missing?

```
public class B extends Thread{
    static int a = 0;

    public static void main(String[] Args){
        B MyB = new B();
        MyB.start();
        runLoop(1000000);
        System.out.println(a);
    }

    public static synchronized void runLoop(int b){
        for(int i = 0; i<b; i++){
            a=i;
        }
    }

    public void run(){
        runLoop(12345678);
    }
}
```

Comment: I ran the code different times and always get a different answer

Comment: Run many threads and after report a result.

Comment: @RomanC Were you answering to my comment? I ran many threads...

Comment: No OP has a singlethreaded model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when you call

```
SomeThread.start();
```

it takes some time to properly start thread which allows thread which is executing this command to execute few of its next lines, like

```
SomeThread.start();//lets say it should print "A"
System.out.print("B");
```

in many cases will print `BA` instead of `AB` and that is what your question is about.

So in case of your code before `MyB` thread will `start()`, main thread can invoke its own `runLoop(1000000);`. Then `MyB` may run `runLoop(12345678);` but now main thread may execute `System.out.println(a);` which is accessing `a` in unsynchronized way so it may show how many times `MyB` iterated at current point of time (so both threads are accessing `a` at the same time which may give different results each time you run your application).

If you claim that you always got as response `999999` then you ware very lucky, or are not showing us your real code (like in case where between `MyB.start();` and `runLoop(1000000);` there is other code which could take enough time to let `MyB.start()` finish like `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It makes sense what you say. One thing is a little unclear. I do get different results now after restarting my computer. Thing is that they are really small. numbers (ex. 8589) compared to what runloop takes as arguments. Can you explain why?

Comment: I think I understand now. We have two threads. Each of them can "jump around" and execute different statements, if I have understood correctly

Comment: @Lebowski "Thing is that they are really small numbers (ex. 8589)" it just means `MyB.run()` is executing `runLoop(12345678);` after main thread finishes executing its `runLoop(1000000);` and code `System.out.println(a);` is executed in same time. To be more precise `MyB.run` was able to iterate small number of times before `System` accessed its `.out` field, then `a` is accessed because we need to know its value before we can invoke `.println(a)`.

Comment: Yes, `runLoop(1000000)` has finished executing but this doesn't mean that `runLoop(12345678);` finished before it. Remember that `MyB.start();` may take some time before calling its `run()` which will internally call `runLoop(12345678);`. This means that there is a chance (quite high) that `runLoop(12345678);` will be executed after `runLoop(1000000)` which means that `MyB` thread will be updating `a` value. But since `main` thread is also accessing `a` in its `println` you are able to see that updating process (once per application execution).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the fact that you ***cannot*** prove your code is deterministic by running it a bunch of times. You ***can*** prove is it not deterministic, however. That is the problem with writing multi-threaded code: it's too easy to misinterpret results according to personal bias. We all do it.

There is something else going on here: the code calls runLoop() indirectly via the start method, which is correct, ***and*** the code calls runLoop() directly in the main method. That is why the code isn't deterministic -- that's the answer to the original question. The explicit call to runLoop() in the main method shouldn't be there. All the main should be doing is kicking off the thread.

Answer (score 0):

When reasoning about thread-safety problems, it may well be that it works on your machine. Or on many machines, under normal conditions. But it does not mean that the program works correctly. Actually, code that "always" worked may break under certain conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Two things here -

1. Single threaded model - To get value 999999 for sure, you should restrict threads accessing it simultaneously. In this case its main thread and the one being started. you can synchronize the class - `synchronized(b.class)` as suggested in earlier answer.
2. Multi threaded model - as you only instance of the class being synchronized  class level resources are still accessible simultaneously. In this output guaranteed to be same always.